# Plugin google maps

Tags: google-maps, maps

Boa tarde pessoal.. Estou usando o plugin gmaps no meu site, mas estou tendo problemas em encontrar uma configuração que preciso...

http://mansanofotografia.com.br/contato

Esse link tem um mapa parecido com o que existe no meu site, porem eu não consigo habilitar a janela com endereço, rota e salvar...

Quem puder me ajudar, agradeço demais!

Boa Tarde para todos!!